# react.js app with nginx gives 404 or refresh

Tags: nginx, node.js, conf

I have a backend node.js application(system directory) and a frontend react application(admin directory). I use nginx as the webserver.

I can load my frontend well. But when I refresh, it gives 404. I have looked in the nginx directives, but I'm not sure how it works, since I didn't setup this project. I know that react uses the react-router, which nginx is not aware of.

My nginx conf file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name lcl.notification.com;
    root /home/development/www/notifications/system/public;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/notify.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/notify.error.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    location / {
        return 301  https://www.google.com;
        break;
    }
    location /panel {
        alias /home/development/www/notifications/admin/build/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Include headers
        include includes/headers.conf;
    }
```

After login, it opens the /panel uri. But on refresh, it gives 404.

Comment: Make a symlink from `alias /home/development/www/notifications/admin/build/` to `alias /home/development/www/notifications/admin/panel/`. Next use `root /home/development/www/notifications/admin` and `try_files $uri $uri/ /panel/index.html;`